# Input get moved to top when rendering div under him

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I created search user component to search for specific users on my website, this component located in navbar, centered aligned to middle, but when i click on search, my component renders a list of available users and my input goes to top of navbar.

[Normal input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZzCI.png)

[Input on focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxrTw.png)

SearchUserComponent:

```
return (
    <div className="flex justify-center flex-col">
      <div>
        <input
          style={inputStyling}
          type="text"
          onChange={onSearchChange}
          onBlur={() => {
            if (!element?.parentElement?.matches(":hover")) {
              setIsVisible(false);
            } else {
              setIsVisible(true);
            }
          }}
          onFocus={() => setIsVisible(true)}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#f4f4f4" }}
        id="listcontainer"
        className=""
      >
        {isVisible &&
          filteredUsers.map((user) => {
            return (
              <div key={user?.id}>
                  <p className="p-2">{user?.username}</p>
                </Link>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
);
```

NavBar:

```
<nav className="sticky z-20 top-0 justify-between [&>.link]:max-xl:hidden w-[100%] p-0 [&>*]:my-auto h-[3.2rem] flex flex-row bg-white border-b">
  <div>
    <Link className="flex pl-4 flex-row justify-center" href="/">
      <Image src={Logo} width={150} height={200} alt="dasds" />
    </Link>
  </div>
  <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
    <SearchUserComponent />
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Probably because the whole #listcontainer element is still in normal flow, so you got  this overflowing the limited height of the navbar element now. This should be absolute positioned.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution, im also added some top property to place it in a right place.